# setup.py : Create commands as for ant script?

Tags: python, ant, packaging, distutils, setup.py

I have a project under python and have a setup.py script that build my egg and .exe file for each realease.
I am used to use ant script, where I can define targets easily.

I may miss something, but I cannot find any documentation that explains how to create such commands with distutils.
(Well, I found [this](http://docs.python.org/distutils/extending.html#integrating-new-commands) actually but this is quite short as a documentation :s)

Here are some examples of what I would like to automate:

- create packages for various platforms (exe, pypi, linux, source)
- build documentation (pdf, html, rst)
- zip my samples, move them to a distant location
- upload new package to pypi
- run tests
- . . .

But most of all, I would like to be able to do it in only one command, just like I would do it with a ant build.

So how do you usually do such tasks with your python projects? 
Though I think it would not be relevant to add my setup.py here, I can do it if needed.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Ant Python tasks](http://code.google.com/p/pyanttasks/)?

> These Ant extensions add some tasks to support Python builds. In
>   particular, Python compile, unit test execution, pydoc generation, and
>   executing Python scripts is supported.

Comment: Yep, actually that's what I currently use but I found several places (including SO) where people were talking of distutils as the 'ant for python'. So I was asking for some more information about this :). Thanks

Comment: Ant seems to be my tool. No problem running it until now